# Calculate EX and Var(X)

Tags: calculus, probability

There are 40 raisins and 30 cakes, a cook puts the raisins randomly in the cakes. Let X be the number of cakes without a single raisin. Calculate the EX and Var(X)

I am not sure if i get this correctly

$$P(X=30)=0$$
$$P(X=29)=(1/30)^{40}*{30\choose 1}$$
$$P(X=29)=(2/30)^{40}*{30\choose 2}-P(X=29)$$
$$P(X=k)=(30-k/30)^{40}*{n\choose k}-...$$

Then calculating the EX will be very difficult, since the expressions will not be eliminated when taking $$ 30*P(X=30)+...+0*P(X=0)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity): The expected number of cakes without raisins is $30$ times the probability that any particular cake has no raisins. The variance is only slightly more involved; express $X$ as a sum $\sum_iX_i$ of indicator variables and use $\operatorname{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ to express the variance in terms of expectations and then again use linearity of expectation, where $X^2$ contains terms of the form $X_iX_j$, so you need to find the probability that two particular cakes have no raisins.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Will the answer be?  $$EX=30*(29/30)^{40}$$ and $$Var(X)=30^2*(28/30)^{40}-EX^2$$

Comment: @ryszardeggink: Almost. In the variance, you treated all products $X_iX_j$ as if $i\neq j$, but $30$ of them are of the form $X_iX_i$.

Comment: Right! it should be $$ Var(x)=29*30(28/30)^{40}+30*(29/30)^{40}-EX^2$$

Comment: @ryszardeggink: Yes, that looks good.